# TextView and RelativeLayout onMeasure called a lot

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm using traceview in attempts to optimize my code. I noticed that TextView.onMeasure() and RelativeLayout.onMeasure() gets called a lot, and I'm trying to see if there is any way I can optimize this. In my ListAdapter, I'm already using ViewHolders, checking if currentView is null as suggested by various google talks/Romain Guy. [Here is a screenshot of my costly functions in traceview.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfGRT.png)

Below is code for my layout in the list, to prove that it's not crazy complicated.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="178dp"
    android:background="@color/Transparent"
    android:clickable="true" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Holder"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="178dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/Transparent" >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/userIcon"
            android:layout_width="141dp"
            android:layout_height="141dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@color/Transparent" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/userInfoSection"
            android:layout_width="143dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/userIcon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/Black" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/MenuButton"
                android:layout_width="31dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_menu" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Name"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="17dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/MenuButton"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Age"
                android:layout_width="39dp"
                android:layout_height="14dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/Name"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/MenuButton"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                style="@style/Text.Default" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Location"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="14dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/Name"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Price"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                style="@style/Text.Default" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageView_caption_loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="115dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/loading_indicator"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to use linearlayout or framelayout they are more  efficient than RelativeLayout.
In the same time, I am puzzled TextView too